# Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to <server> closed

Tags: ansible

I am running my playbok from Ansible Tower. As per the Job output server is able to connect, server is able to connect

> ok: [localhost -> ] => {
>       "ping_result": {
>           "ansible_facts": {
>               "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
>           },
>           "changed": false,
>           "failed": false,
>           "ping": "pong"
>       } }

But after which I get the below error,

> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection
>   to servername closed.  ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER:
>   xyz

*

> fatal: [servername: FAILED! => {
>       "ansible_facts": {}, 
>       "changed": false, 
>       "failed_modules": {
>           "setup": {
>               "failed": true, 
>               "module_stderr": "Shared connection to servername.\r\n", 
>               "module_stdout": "", 
>               "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
>               "rc": 1
>           }
>       }, 
>       "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n" }

*

Comment: Hi Frnd, welcome to SO. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62036372/edit) and fix the formatting, as it's currently illegible, and because of that it's hard to tell what you're actually asking for help with here. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section